# Desktop launchers stopped working

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with the default desktop environments. After copying a file to my desktop, somehow all launchers stopped showing their icons, the .desktop extension appeared and I can no longer launch them. They are still set as executables, but when I double click them they simple get opened in Arronax.

I would appreciate help with getting them to work again.